# TCP write and read commands give different results when I put breakpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tcp, async-await, networkstream

I want to get a weight from a scale in C# so I'm using a TCP connection for that.

This is my code,

```
private TcpClient _client;
public NetworkStream Stream { get; private set; }

public ScalesService()
{
    _client = new TcpClient();
}

async public Task<string> TestRead()
{
    var responseLength = 1024;
    var readResponse = new byte[responseLength];

    string result = "";

    Console.WriteLine("connecting...");
    await _client.ConnectAsync("10.100.200.70", 1182);
    Console.WriteLine("connected!");

    Stream = _client.GetStream();

    var cmdUser = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user admin\n");
    await Stream.WriteAsync(cmdUser, 0, cmdUser.Length);

    var countCmdUser = await Stream.ReadAsync(readResponse, 0, readResponse.Length);
    var responseCmdUser = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readResponse, 0, countCmdUser);

    var cmdRead = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("read wt0501\n");

    await Stream.WriteAsync(cmdRead, 0, cmdRead.Length);

    var countCmdRead = await Stream.ReadAsync(readResponse, 0, readResponse.Length);
    var responseCmdRead = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readResponse, 0, countCmdRead);

    //result = responseCmdRead;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseCmdRead))
    {
        // Expected Return: [00R001~       10300~]
        var responseArray = responseCmdRead.Split('~');
        if (responseArray.Length >= 2)
        {
            var weightString = responseArray[1];

            float grossNetWt;
            result = weightString;
            //if (float.TryParse(weightString, out grossNetWt))
            //{
            //    result = grossNetWt;
            //}
        }
    }

    var cmdQuit = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("quit\n");
    await Stream.WriteAsync(cmdQuit, 0, cmdQuit.Length);

    return result;
}
```

It seems like the stream doesn't wait to send me the full answer. I got different results when I put breakpoints or not. Is there a better way to do that? I was thinking that the `await` would be a good solution.

Comment: TCP is just a stream of bytes. There's no guarantee that what's sent in a single Write call on one end will be delivered to a single Read call on the other end. It may be chopped up into smaller bits, or lumped into larger groups. The bytes will be in the same order but that's as much as you can expect.  You need to analyze the bytes you get to find the boundaries of the protocol you're using. That appears to be `\n` (byte 0x0A) in this case, based on what you're sending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comment, TCP/IP sockets are streams of *bytes*, not *packets*. If you want to read/write an entire message, you need to use some kind of [message framing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html).

Since you already have a device, the type of message framing should be documented in the device's protocol specification. From the example code you posted, it looks like it's using a message delimiter of `\n`. So you'll need to have a read loop that adds bytes to a buffer until you see the `\n`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have to admit I’m kind of lost and it doesn’t really help :/ can you be more precise on what I should do?

Comment: Did you read the link? Have you tried reading into a buffer?

Comment: Yes I read it but with not a lot of experience in that concept, it’s not really easy to understand everything. By reading the buffer, do you mean using System.IO.BinaryReader?

Comment: I mean you'll need to create a buffer like a `List<char>` and append each array of bytes as you read it until you find a `\n`.

Comment: Ok so for example this is the answer I receive after the connection : `\n\r53 Ready for user\n\r>` I guess the delimiter is `>` (all the answers finish like that `\n\r>`). I also know the size of the answer (22 bytes) I should get (it's always the same except maybe for the last one which contain the weight and that can have different values). Would it be safe to loop until the length of the buffer is 22?

Comment: @bibout182: You'd need to look into the protocol details document for that. And possibly ask a different question on SO, since that's not really the same topic as this one.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for your help.